# Pandas - sort_values not sorting converted float percentages correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe where I want to show the percentages of certain values. I calculate them to decimal values and then I apply a format string to get them to percentages. When the dataframe is converted to percentages, it cannot sort the percentages properly.

```
d = {'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'percentage':[0.15, 0.65, 0.7, 0.3, 1]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
test_df

name    percentage
0   A   0.15
1   B   0.65
2   C   0.70
3   D   0.30
4   E   1.00
```

When sorting the values above with the sort_values function, we receive:

```
test_df.sort_values('percentage')

    name    percentage
0   A   0.15
3   D   0.30
1   B   0.65
2   C   0.70
4   E   1.00
```

I then convert the decimals into percentages (this is mostly for visualization purposes in the graphs) and try to sort it, this time ascending as my dataset is a couple of hundred rows and I just want to show the top 10:

```
perc_sort = test_df
perc_sort['percentage'] = perc_sort['percentage'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
perc_sort.sort_values('percentage', ascending=False)

name    percentage
2   C   70.00%
1   B   65.00%
3   D   30.00%
0   A   15.00%
4   E   100.00%
```

Why is the 100% at the bottom? I guess there's some issue with the string, probably that the 0 comes before the number 1. But is there a way to sort the actual percentages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need sorting integers, else numbers are sorting wrong - `'100'` < `5`, because `'1'` < `'5'`:

```
perc_sort.sort_values('percentage', ascending=False)
perc_sort['percentage'] = perc_sort['percentage'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
```

If values are already strings you can create helper column filled by numbers and sorting by it:

```
perc_sort = test_df.copy()
perc_sort['percentage'] = perc_sort['percentage'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
```

---

```
perc_sort['new'] = perc_sort['percentage'].str.strip('%').astype(float)
df = perc_sort.sort_values('new', ascending=False)

print(df)
  name percentage    new
4    E    100.00%  100.0
2    C     70.00%   70.0
1    B     65.00%   65.0
3    D     30.00%   30.0
0    A     15.00%   15.0
```

Or using [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with `[::-1]` for indices of descended sorted values and pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
new = perc_sort['percentage'].str.strip('%').astype(float)
df = perc_sort.iloc[new.argsort()[::-1]]

print(df)
  name percentage
4    E    100.00%
2    C     70.00%
1    B     65.00%
3    D     30.00%
0    A     15.00%
```

Comment: The first strip of code seems to just be switching places of the code, not resulting in any new sorting.

The other includes creating a new column. I can see that working, but would that be the only solution?

Comment: @marreBUS - Added 2 solution, added to answer also your data