# Sort return incorrect result after turning number to percent

Tags: python, pandas

I perform sort when the value is float and it works fine.
Then I format the number to percent and sort again and the result is wrong.
I notice that in percent format, a data type is an object instead of a float.

Can anyone please tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

##### What I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
          'number': [0.2127,0.2708,0.3014,0.40,-0.0022,-0.0788,0.1233,0.0828]})

df.sort_values(by=['id','number'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
print(df)

# turn to percent
df['number']=df['number'].map(lambda n: '{:,.2%}'.format(n))
df.sort_values(by=['id','number'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: You are converting numbers into string by using the `format()` function. If you wished to round a `float` value to two decimals, you should use `lambda n: round(n, 2)` instead of turning it to a string.

Comment: Looks like you ran into the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385933/pandas-sort-values-not-sorting-converted-float-percentages-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67881067/sort-return-incorrect-result-after-turning-number-to-percent#comment119982480_67881067).

You need to sort as numbers because `'100'` < `5` . There is no data type for percentage, it is actually a string.

```
df['number']=df['number'].map(lambda n: '{:,.2%}'.format(n))
```

The code above is taking each number and map the percentage string formatting function onto it ([Ctrl+F this link: "Expressing a percentage"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)).

One easy way, that you've brushed real close to is to sort first (while as floats) before converting to percentage:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
          'number': [0.2127,0.2708,0.3014,0.40,-0.0022,-0.0788,0.1233,0.0828]})

# sort
df.sort_values(by=['id','number'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)

# turn to percent
df['number']=df['number'].map(lambda n: '{:,.2%}'.format(n))

# result
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I see it now.